# Using monaco-editor in dojotoolkit based application

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd, monaco-editor

Did someone try to use Monaco-editor inside a Dojotoolkit based application?

In its latest version, this framework is supporting AMD modules, and monaco-editor is providing one too.
require.config is not recognized so you need to use dojo configuration to reference 'vs' module.
I was then able to get it using define at start of my module.

But then, I'm seeing a strange error in editor.main.js:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined
    at Object.CSSPlugin.load (editor.main.js:118)
    ...
```

'this' object is referencing the main Monaco object while it should reference CSSPlugin.

Can this be linked to dojo expecting one module per file, generally not wrapped in IIFE?
If so, are you aware of any way to build monaco-editor so that it generates individual AMD files for each modules?

Comment: In case someone wants to see the error in live, I've created this stackblitz showing the error: [stackblitz - monaco-dojo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/monaco-dojo)

Comment: I need to do the same thing. Any luck since February? Thanks! If I find out how to do it I'll answer!

Comment: @damix911 Hi, we found a hacky way to workaround this issue, described at https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1864

Comment: Thank you! Since then I had resorted to use CodeMirror, but I may give Monaco another shot.